# Why alternators are used to generate DC?

Tags: motor, dc, generator, alternator

Why is it that to generate DC, it's often an alternator that's used? Couldn't commutator rings be added and do without AC-DC conversion?

I'm asking because I wonder how efficient it usually is for a typical RC car motor to be used as a DC generator.

Thanks

Comment: Like for braking purposes? Like a hybrid vehicle? You should learn to use google, this was the first link that popped up https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_differences_between_a_generator_and_an_alternator

Comment: Compare the efficiency of a diode to the friction & arcing losses of a high-speed commutator ring with sliding brushes. The diode wins ;)

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific? It is difficult to glean whether you are interested in regenerative braking, automobiles, RC cars, wind turbines, or some combination thereof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automobiles, you can be sure that alternators including the rectifier are less expensive to manufacture. They do have slip rings so that the excitation can be controlled to regulate the output voltage with changing speed and load. The efficiency is probably comparable to a DC generator with a commutator, but automotive manufacturers were likely thinking only of manufacturing cost when they switched from commutator generators about 50 years ago.

There are fewer DC generators larger than automotive generators, but some are manufactured specifically for use with wind turbines. Some of them have permanent magnets and no slip rings. Some of them have AC-DC-AC converters in order to have both battery energy storage and AC output. They are said to be competitive with other types of generator systems in terms of efficiency. They are also attractive because they can run at lower speeds eliminating the need for a speed increasing gearbox.

RC car motors can be either permanent-magnet DC motors with commutators or brushless DC motors. The brushless motors can be used as AC generators and the output can be rectified to provide DC. The output voltage is proportional to speed in both cases, so both need electronic regulators to provide constant DC. The brushless DC motors are probably a little more efficient. I suspect that they are a little higher quality because they are part of a more expensive system including the electronic speed controller require to use them.

Answer (score 6):

Brushes and commutators which need to actually switch current will often be far more wear-prone than slip-ring assemblies which don't need to perform any switching functions.  This excess wear comes about both because it's hard to make a smooth surface with multiple separated contacts (without the space between the contacts being higher or lower than the surrounding contacts themselves), and because switching contacts under load puts extra stress on them; while a motor or generator with many windings will put smaller switching stresses on the commutator than one with fewer, a non-switching slip ring will produce none.

Answer (score 1):

Regenerative braking systems usually include the use of DC drive motors, as the magnetic coupling is stronger than that of AC alternators. Of course, eddy current braking systems use a solid disk, such as on trams and trains, but the energy dissipated into the wheels as heat under braking cannot easily be captured as electric energy to charge a battery, unless a rethink of the systems of brushes and commutators are employed using modern materials.